# Ubuntu bluetooth showing a number of unknown devices

Tags: 20.04, bluetooth

I am trying to connect my raspberry pi (running with ubuntu 20.10). My pi is not connecting to my bt speakers. When I turn my bluetooth on, it shows a number of devices:

[image]

And keeps showing them even when I turn the bluetooth off. Any reason why this is happening? I trust the device I am trying to connect followed by pair command, sometimes it disconnects itself, sometimes it throws authentication error. Any help would be really appreciated.