# Many "Unknown" devices in Bluetooth settings tab, keep growing over time

Tags: 20.04, bluetooth

On startup, when I go to connect my wireless headphones to my laptop, I notice that there are a couple of "Unknown" devices alongside ones that my laptop has picked up (neighbours' or mine). And puzzlingly, the number of "Unknown" devices grows over time (it starts off with a couple but just keeps adding more over time). Is there anything I can do to prevent this? Clear them up periodically at least? Is it an issue with my Bluetooth radio?

I'm on 20.04. Not sure if my issue is related to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1335385/ubuntu-bluetooth-showing-a-number-of-unknown-devices).

[image]